# Maven dependency version override not working

Tags: maven

In a Maven project, I have the modules `core` and `custom` (+ about 20 more of mine).

`core` has a dependency `dep`, which in turn depends on `dep-core`. Sadly, the `dep-core` version it would automatically get (say version 1.0) has a security issue. I used the `<dependencyManagement>` tag in my `core` project to overwrite the version of `dep-core` with a newer version (say version 2.0) without the security issue.

However, when I execute the `dependency:tree` plugin on my `custom` project, it says the `custom` project depends on `core`, which depends on `dep`, which depends on the *outdated* version of `dep-core`, despite the `core` project defining a version override. It seems that override only works *inside* the `core` project but gets ignored in `custom`.

How do I fix it without adding the same override to the `custom` project (and thus to all sub-projects using `core`, because that's a lot - around 20)?

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a known design flaw in `dependencyManagement`.

You have essentially two choices:

1. You define a dependency on `dep` on `core` (not dependencyManagement, but a dependency)
2. You use the flatten Maven plugin to create a POM for `core` with removed dependencyManagement (and containing the correct dependency).

Comment: It seems the problem was fixed by defining the version in the highest project. I didn't know adding a dependency in the dependencyManagement will not download the dependency into project that don't need it. ^^'